# React Components not rendering with my path setup

Tags: reactjs

Trying to render some components in my pages folder but Im not able to access them when I run the npm start command. [image: my app.js file where im trying to render NewMeetupPage and FavoritePage]

[image: file structure]

Comment: **A)** Plesae do not post images of the code (folder structure is okay). **B)** There is a typo on line 4 (`NewMeetupPage` is imported from `pages/Favorites`). **C)** To me, there is not sufficient info to determine if something is wrong. I hope other answerers will be able to help.

Comment: What is your error?